# How can I make my menu expand all the subitems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a list menu with some JavaScript code that makes it collapse and expand `.onClick`.

Although I could only make it show 1 item because every time I try a new solution like a `for` loop or `case` I can't get it to work.

This is my current code:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="main"><a>Diagonóstico</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_di1"> › Grátis (na compra de qualquer serviço) </a></li>
    <li class="main"><a>Hardware</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha1"> › Instalação/Configuração de Componentes</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha2"> › Instalação/Configuração de Periféricos </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha3"> › Limpeza interna/externa </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha4"> › Cooling Pack </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha5"> › Performance Pack </a></li>
    <li class="main"><a>Software</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_so1"> › Actualização de Sistema Operativo </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_so2"> › Instalação de Sistema Operativo </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_so3"> › Instalação de Drivers e Aplicações </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_so4"> › Configurações de internet e redes wireless </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_so5"> › Legalize o seu PC </a></li>
    <li class="main"><a>Backup</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ba1"> › Backup de dados até 4GB </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ba2"> › Backup and Go </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ba3"> › Suportes Danificados </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ba4"> › Recuperação de dados sem intervenção física </a></li>
    <li class="main"><a>Segurança</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_se1"> › Remoção de Vírus e Spyware </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_se2"> › Instalação de anti-vírus </a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_se3"> › Configurações de Controlo Parental </a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("li.sub:not(:first)").hide();
    $("li.main a").click(function () {
        $("li.sub").slideUp("fast");
        $(this).parent("li.main").next("li.sub").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDYMz/2/)** for it.

I was thinking about a `for` loop that goes all the way trough each sub-menu category for instance:

```
for(var i=1; i<5; i++) {
    $(this).parent("li.main").next("li.sub_ha" + i).slideDown("slow");
}
```

Then doing this for each main menu giving each of them a class `menu1,menu2,menu3` etc.

Comment: Do you want to collapse and expand all of your list items, or just the ones between a pair of 'main' list items?

Comment: You should change the structure, subitems should be children of the items, structurally not semantically.

Comment: @undefined how come? sorry i didnt' quite get it.

Comment: @ckersch just the ones with class sub in between each main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` only selects the next sibling of the selected element, you can use `nextUntil` mehod.

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil("li.main").slideDown("slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruf6z/

```
$(function() {
    var $subitems = $("li.sub");
    $subitems.not(':first').hide();

    $("li.main a").click(function() {
        var $targets = $(this).parent().nextUntil("li.main").slideDown("slow");
        $subitems.not($targets).slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruf6z/1/

Comment: **Waw!** Superb my dearest friend! www.datamaia.pt/serv that's the result! Only problem is it seems like jumping at the end of the animation. But shouldn't be a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("li.sub").slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: but for that to work i must change each main class to a different one and then have 1 script for each of the classes ? check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/LjReC/

Comment: Oh, now I get it, you just want to show the ones in the same node. If so, you need to redo your HTML and properly structure it: make a UL with one LI for each top item and then inside each li make another UL and one LI for each subitem. After that you can just show/hide the current item's children.

Comment: thanks for the help i understand that would make it more simple, altho since undefined gave me a fitting solution i'll use that. tyvm

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do this semantically. If you want to say the course, I would suggest giving each group of child items their own class. You can search for the class of the child items, and then use that class to find everything in your subgroup, and then run the `.slideDown()` method on that group.

I made a [modified version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDYMz/4/) that shows how to do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fDYMz/1/ here's why having the sub**_ha1**,etc. is important. you can check the main website i'm making here www.datamaia.pt/serv thanks

Comment: If you need to target a specific one of the sub items, why not make it an ID instead of a class?

Comment: you mean so i can have same class and different id for each . outrageous idea! ty i'll look into that.